# Converting a Java threads to AKKA actors

Tags: akka

I do have Java application with lot of threads and thread pools. Can we use AKKA to replace the threads and thread pools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what your threads are doing. Are they doing blocking IO or taking locks and sharing mutable data between themselves? If so akka might not be a great fit as actors generally should avoid blocking for io or locks. On the other hand, if the threads do isolated non-blocking work, and can communicate via message passing, akka is probably a good fit.

Comment: @YerraVen Just to add: One important point to note is that, don't think actors have a one-to-one correspondence to threads. So if I have a system with 5 concurrent threads processing parallely, that does not mean I can replace it with 5 actors and expect to behave the same way. It will depend on the dispatcher threads being scheduled by the akka framework.<p>Well shared this, because initially I myself expected similar behavior! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you absolutely can. Be careful about the above poster's response. That isn't entirely accurate. Actors can do blocking I/O. You just use child actors to represent each blocking connection. The newbie mistake would be to treat actors the same way you would treat a thread... in which case, the poster above's answer would be right. But, if you pass off the blocking to a lower actor and use an ad-hoc actor each time, you'll never have to block the main throughput.

But, forgive me. I have gone off track. In short, yes, you can. But keep in mind there will be a learning curve. Actors programming is a different paradigm and it needs to be handled a bit differently.

However, programming concurrency with actors is leagues easier than with threads and locking (literally). Just make your app reactive instead of time-based and many concurrency concerns just stop existing.

Check out the AKKA docs on their site. They are very thorough. Also the books Akka concurrency and effective Akka. Just keep 'em on the desk as a reference.